# Troubleshooting the sense of this asm x86 code

Tags: c, assembly, x86, instructions

First of all, here is the assembler code:

```
/           0x000006a0      55             push rbp                             
|           0x000006a1      4889e5         mov rbp, rsp                         
|           0x000006a4      4883ec10       sub rsp, 0x10                        
|           0x000006a8      488d05b50000.  lea rax, str.AAAA           ; 0x764  

|           0x000006af      488945f8       mov qword [local_8h], rax  
|           0x000006b3      488b45f8       mov rax, qword [local_8h]

|           0x000006b7      4889c6         mov rsi, rax                         
|           0x000006ba      488d3da80000.  lea rdi, 0x00000769         ; "%s"   
|           0x000006c1      b800000000     mov eax, 0                           
|           0x000006c6      e895feffff     call sym.imp.printf         ;[2] ; i 
|           0x000006cb      b800000000     mov eax, 0                           
|           0x000006d0      c9             leave                                
\           0x000006d1      c3             ret
```

to this c program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    char* a = "AAAA";

    printf("%s", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Especially I have a question to this code snipped:

```
|           0x000006af      488945f8       mov qword [local_8h], rax            
|           0x000006b3      488b45f8       mov rax, qword [local_8h]
```

What is the sense of these two instructions? I only see the same instruction one way and than reversed. But why is that?

Here are some further information to the executable:

```
blksz    0x0
block    0x100
fd       6
file     demo
format   elf64
iorw     false
mode     -r--
size     0x20e0
humansz  8.2K
type     DYN (Shared object file)
arch     x86
binsz    6559
bintype  elf
bits     64
canary   false
class    ELF64
crypto   false
endian   little
havecode true
intrp    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
lang     c
linenum  true
lsyms    true
machine  AMD x86-64 architecture
maxopsz  16
minopsz  1
nx       true
os       linux
pcalign  0
pic      true
relocs   true
relro    partial relro
rpath    NONE
static   false
stripped false
subsys   linux
va       true
```

Comment: You should inspect non-debug code - i.e. code that has these unnecessary stores elided.

Comment: Compilers usually use very simple rules to break your source code down into a sequence of primitive steps (sometimes called "intermediate code".) Then, they _optimize_ the intermediate code to eliminate steps that are redundant or wasteful.  You appear to have compiled this code with optimizations turned off.

Comment: You compiled your code without optimizations. Unsurprisingly, compilers emit useless weird code when you tell them not to optimize!

Comment: @fuz Your statement sounds a little like "compiler suppliers make the difference between optimised output and non-optimised output by introducing chaff into the non-optimized output". I think the compiler suppliers could see that as an insult. Also, in my experience, the optimised version is much weirder, but with good, if complex, reasons.

Comment: @Yunnosch At least gcc turns off register allocation, uses a simpler instruction selector and generates extra shitty code without optimization. That requires extra code to support, so in a sense, yes, compiler writers do make code extra shitty without optimizations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines are seperate from each other:

The first line belongs to the line `char* a = "AAAA";`, saving the value of the variable to RAM.

The second line accesses the variable from RAM for the line `printf("%s", a);` as the parameter.

Technically, both lines would be optional, as you could have written:

```
printf("%s", "AAAA");
```

**EDIT:** For skipping this unnecessary code, you could enable automatic optimizations (for GCC: -O2)

Comment: Or, instead of eliminating the local variable, `a` from the source code, the programmer could turn on optimizations and let the compiler do it.  It might not be obvious from this simple example, but hand-optimizing source code usually makes it less readable, and usually is not as effective as letting the compiler do it.

Comment: You're absolutely right. My example should just show why the assembly lines come up.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your disassembler is broken (or at least "too smart") and "helpfully" giving you different, confusing, information from what one would normally expect.  These two lines:

```
|           0x000006af      488945f8       mov qword [local_8h], rax            
|           0x000006b3      488b45f8       mov rax, qword [local_8h]
```

should be

```
|           0x000006af      488945f8       mov qword [rbp-8h], rax            
|           0x000006b3      488b45f8       mov rax, qword [rbp-8h]
```

They access memory in the stack frame indirectly via the `rbp` register.  Such memory is used by the compiler for local variables, thus the "local" in what the disassembler is showing.

Comment: OP wasn't asking what does `local_8h` mean.  OP was asking what is the purpose of the second instruction when the value that it loads into `rax` can not possibly be different from the value that already is in `rax`?  Answer is, because each of the two lines was generated from a different source code line, and optimization was turned off.